# Is there an alternative to using FileProvider to get a uri for installing Android apk?

Tags: android, uri, compatibility, android-fileprovider

So I've run into an issue with uri exposure when trying to install an apk. I have written a library that auto-updates android applications and then installs the new apk with the following code.

```
Uri uri = VersionManagerUtil.getFileDestinationUri(apkDir, mParameters.getPackageName());

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_REQUEST_INSTALL);
```

This however does not work for api 24+ due to the FileUriExposedException so I switched to a FileProvider to get the Uri

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

This works great... However, FileProvider requires the following dependency 
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'` which is problematic because all of the projects I would like to use this library on would need to have the same version of the support library. So are there any non-hacky ways to resolve the issue of the FileUriExposedException? Or is there a different way to install an apk that avoids this issue all together?

Answer (score 1):

> However, FileProvider requires the following dependency compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'

First, the version is up to you, and the current one (as of when I am posting this answer) is `26.1.0`.

Second, the actual artifact for `FileProvider` is `support-core-utils`. Requiring `support-v4` will pull in `support-core-utils` via transitive dependencies.

> which is problematic because all of the projects I would like to use this library on would need to have the same version of the support library

Or a compatible one. `FileProvider` has been around for a few years now.

> So are there any non-hacky ways to resolve the issue of the FileUriExposedException?

You can use `FileProvider`. Or, you can write your own `ContentProvider` that serves up the file.

> Or is there a different way to install an apk that avoids this issue all together?

Not that I am aware of.